# ASIHttpRequest request:didReceiveBytes: not working as expected

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I'm sure there's a very easy explanation to this, but I'm tearing my hair out over the matter.

```
    -(void)addRequestWithUrl:(NSURL *)url savePath:(NSString *)path
    {
      ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
      request.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:path, @"savePath", nil];
      networkQueue.showAccurateProgress = YES;
      [self.networkQueue addOperation:request];
      [self.networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
    }

    -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes
    {
       DLog(@"bytes: %llu", bytes);
    }
```

didReceiveBytes is not ever called. If I set the download progress delegate to each request instead of the queue the didReceiveBytes method is called, but only after each request is completely finished, and always with a value of 1.

Any suggestions what's wrong here? (working on iOS btw)

Comment: Did Hursh's solution actually work for you? Because it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it took me a while to figure this one out, I got the same result until I started to look into the ASIHTTPRequest code. All you have to do is add:

```
request.showAccurateProgress = YES;
```

before you networkQueue.showAccurateProgress = YES; because otherwise it does not read the individual head info of each file and add up the bytes.

Answer (score 4):

It may help:

```
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveBytes:)];
```